# UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesW returns fails with error code ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND even file already exists

Tags: c, winapi

I am compiling and running the project [libwdi](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi). It is a USB driver installer for windows.

In the part where an INF should be installed using `UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesW()` function, it returns FALSE `0` and the `GetLastError()` value is `2` which corresponds to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

```
ret = UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesW(hwndParent, wHardwareId, wFullInfPath, InstallFlags, bRebootRequired);
err = GetLastError();
```

I debugged the code, made sure that `wFullInfPath` exists in the system and the `wHardwareId` is correct as specified in device manager, also

`bRebootRequired` is `NULL`,

`InstallFlags` is `INSTALLFLAG_FORCE`.

Why is the driver not installed ? Why `UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesW()` does not return `TRUE`?

Comment: look in  `DPINST.LOG` (in `c:\windows`) and look here for more info

Comment: I cleared the file, re-run the application but nothing is logged inside it.

Comment: We are good, but we are not mind readers. If we cannot see the input to your call, there's not much help you can expect. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The source code is that in the github project. In installer.c, I am trying to install libusb-win32 driver for a connected usb device with specific vid and pid.

Comment: This project should generate an INF driver file, create a trusted certificate authority in windows and self sign the driver with it, then call   UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesW() to install it.

Comment: in your link ansi api used (`A`) and `UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesU` which convert ansi to Unicode. may be here error ? in all case `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` mean `The path specified for FullInfPath does not exist`

Comment: Examining the process with process monitor running may provide some insight as to why it thinks the file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort and time, I posted an answer, sorry for this dummy question.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the library, which generates the INF file, produces a defected INF file. It has some placeholders for unneeded files which makes Windows search for these non-existing files.